# Does Nosgoth exist?

Tags: steam, humble-bundle

So, there might or might not be a game called Nosgoth, it's a multiplayer F2P spin-off of the Legacy of Kain series.

According to some sources, the game was never finished ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosgoth) says it's cancelled, [Eurogamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-04-08-legacy-of-kain-spin-off-nosgoth-cancelled) reports the same, It's not on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=nosgoth)).

However, there's a [collection on Humblebundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/legacy-of-kain-collection) that lists a Nosgoth Key as it's content.
Also, a [Google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=nosgoth+key) reveals that there *might* be some keys out there.

So, if I bought that Humble collection, would I be able to use the key at all?
Does Nosgoth still exist in 2017?

Comment: I played that game some Years ago and the first thing after opening the game was a login screen. To play, you had to make a second account on there Login-Server (wich was super buggy at the time). So if the sources are correct and they shut-down then the Login servers are probably also down. But to test it out im going to reinstall and check

Comment: `Wiki says it's cancelled` that's because it wasn't officially released - it was playable in an (open? at later stages, at least) Beta. It didn't do that well, so it got canned, which means no "official" release date as it never went out of beta.

Comment: Anyway, as another note - the game wasn't _that_ good. Not bad, by all means, there were some promises but it wasn't exceptional in any way, either. It's probably why it didn't really do that well to begin with. It was a 10v10 (IIRC) and coop and class-based. It reminded me a lot of _Alien vs Predator 2_ multiplayer, especially since there was a vampire that could jump and then the humans' classes wielded different weapons, e.g., a grenadier. Probably a big reason for the failure was the payment model - not pay to win but definitely a lot of stuff you could buy for power. While in beta.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to play it. Nosgoth has been shut-down between May 31st, 2016 and June 1st, 2016. The developers of the game talked about it in [this post](http://forums.eu.square-enix.com/showthread.php?t=189318&p=2213850#post2213850) on the official forum of the game:

> May 31st – Nosgoth will go into maintenance for the final time at 11:59 PM PDT. It will no longer be possible to log into Nosgoth after this point.
>
> June 1st – Nosgoth game servers are taken offline. (Those who log in prior to maintenance on the 31st may be able to continue to play until this point).

So there is no way to play to this game anymore nowadays.

Those keys that you can find on Google are most of the time from really old posts (2014 for a lot of them), or probably from sites who didn't think about removing them now (or are not even aware of the game not existing anymore). This Humble Bundle collection has also been there since a long time now. It seems that the content of it hasn't been modified since then, so it's probably an error from them. If you would get such a key, you couldn't do anything with it.

Comment: So i reinstalled the game and here is the only thing that happens. http://imgur.com/a/AfwLd

Comment: I just realised I have this game in my steam account but never played it before. This sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly that game has been announced dead by its creators. To clarify, it was a 5v5 PvP with asymmetric classes, segregated into Humans and Vampires.

I loved that game to bits while it was alive and to day I miss it. I believe the reasons for its demise was not lack of unique features, bad design or boring gameplay, but mostly failure of marketing leading to declining playerbase, in a game that already has a steep curve.

I still keep the Nosgoth binaries as a memento and a slight hope that something can come out of that (even with my sub-par reverse-engineering skills). I really wish Squire Enix and Psyonix decided to at least sell the IP if not release it open-source for free. Nosgoth had a small playerbase but a large part of it really cared about the game.

Pity you never got to try it, I notice the game often seemed to be either a person's exact cup of tea or not at all.

Comment: This is really just an ode to Nosgoth with 10 words dedicated to answering the question.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Is that a bad thing, actually?

Comment: @Dragomok Of course it is. The poster's opinion of the game does not answer the question at all, and it's the majority of the text in it. And considering the question was already answered much more thoroughly, I'm surprised to see this answer is still around.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer On the other hand, I feel this answer provides some vital (anecdotal, subjective) context to the reason why Nosgoth is closed, which has value in itself. This kind of hands-on expertise is the kind I'm looking when I use any StackExchange site.

Comment: @Dragomok Such information would be better suited to comments, in my opinion, for two reasons: it's only tangentially related to the question being asked, and it's mostly speculation from the user, not an official source. The only relevant information in this answer is "Sadly that game has been announced dead by its creators".